# How to iterate through multiple tables in Lua

Tags: lua

Okay, so i've looked around everywhere on stackoverflow for a answer to this burning question.

So the issue i am having is i wanna iterate/loop thru tables.

But my tables that i take from DB in to lua is looking like this:

```
{"cid":"12"}{"cid":"13"}
```

I usually loop it like

```
for k, v in pairs(table) do
end
```

Both are in a row like that, so how would i iterate thru them? to find if a number matches the employees number..?

Comment: what you've posted is not a Lua table. please format your input data properly

Comment: Yea my bad its json encoded table

Answer (score 0):

Given a table like this:

```
local t = {{cid = "12"},{cid = "13"}}
local employeeNumber = "13"
```

You would probably not iterate through the inner tables as they only have a single field which you can simply index.

```
for i,v in ipairs(t) do
  if v.cid == employeeNumber then
    print("match at field " .. i)
  end
end
```

Aside that nested tables are traversed using nested loops.

Comment: But what if i have multiple in db? Like after each other,

Comment: @infamous: That's what this answer describes in the `t` table. If that's not correct, please add a table to your question that shows how your input data is formatted.